# Azure Pipeline - Deployment job to start webserver using script only temporarily starts the server

Tags: shell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, virtual-machine

I am creating a azure devops pipeline to bring down my application server and bring it up automatically later. Currently i make use of deployment job with environment mapped to 2 virtual machines so that application server is automatically brought down and up on those virtual machines.

```
  - stage: Start_Applications
    displayName : "Start the Applications in Test"
    dependsOn : 'Start_Virtual_Machine'
    jobs:
      - deployment: start_apps_in_test_vms
        displayName: "Starting openliberty Servers"
        environment:
          name: 'XXX-TEST-APPLICATION'
          resourceType: VirtualMachine
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                 - task: Bash@3
                   displayName: 'Start of openliberty after weekend'
                   inputs:
                    targetType: 'inline'
                    script: |
                      # Exit immediately if any of the command fails
                      set -e
                      echo "~ Start of Applications after weekend - Start ~"
                      /appl/openliberty/wlp/bin/server start xxxserver -- --databaseName=$(SqlDatabaseName) --serverName=$(SqlServerUrl) --portNumber=$(SqlPortNumber)
                       echo "~ Start of Applications after weekend - Completed ~"
```

In the output from the pipeline run i see

~ Start of Applications after weekend - Start ~
Starting server xxxserver.
Server xxxserver started with process ID 22848.

~ Start of Applications after weekend - Completed ~

But if i login to the server after the execution of the pipeline run then i see application server is still down. I am able to manually login and start the application server and it stays started. So no issues with application deployed on the server.

Can you please help me in understanding what i am doing wrong ?